# Dynamic where condition in linq query expression

Tags: linq, dynamic, expression, where-clause

My Code :

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> whrRowEnum;
whrRowEnum  = from r in dtInput.AsEnumerable()
        where r.Field<string>("EMP_DEP") == "DEP1"
        orderby EMP_DEP
        select r;
```

The above code is working fine due to hard coded where condition, but In run-time I need to add multiple where condition in my linq query like r.Field("EMP_DEP") == "DEP1" && r.Field("EMP_ID") == "EMP1"

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda syntax to compose your query based on conditions:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = dtInput.AsEnumerable();

if (condition1)
   query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>("EMP_DEP") == "DEP1");

if (condition2)
   query = query.Where(r => r.Field<string>("EMP_ID") == "EMP1");

var whrRowEnum = query.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("EMP_DEP"));
```

Another option is adding conditions to query filter

```
whrRowEnum  = from r in dtInput.AsEnumerable()
              where (!condition1 || (r.Field<string>("EMP_DEP") == "DEP1")) &&
                    (!condition2 || (r.Field<string>("EMP_ID") == "EMP1"))
              orderby EMP_DEP
              select r;
```

Comment: It should be `(!condition1 || (...)) && (!condition2 || (...))` or the where clause is equal to false if condition1 or 2 are false.

Comment: @Sergey For the second option, is there a way to outsource that condition block to a method/function?

Comment: @ibubi you can use whatever you want - the only condition is boolean output. So `where IsFoo(r)` is totally fine. But in that case I would stick to method syntax `rows.Where(IsFoo)` is more readable